# R Programming - Creating Categories

Tags: r, categories

I am a beginner in R and learning how to create Categories from dataset. For some reason, my output results are not printing out correctly. Here is the code for the categories I am trying calculate:

```
# Create a new variable to categorize people based on their TotalSteps.
merge_all2$TotalSteps_category <-
(merge_all2$TotalSteps >= 0 & merge_all2$TotalSteps < 3000) | 
(merge_all2$TotalSteps >= 3000 & merge_all2$TotalSteps < 10000) |
(merge_all2$TotalSteps >= 10000 & merge_all2$TotalSteps < 20000) | 
(merge_all2$TotalSteps >= 20000 & merge_all2$TotalSteps < 36019)

# Assign category names
merge_all2$TotalSteps_category[merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == 1] <- "Less Active"
merge_all2$TotalSteps_category[merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == 2] <- "Moderately Active"
merge_all2$TotalSteps_category[merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == 3] <- "Active"
merge_all2$TotalSteps_category[merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == 4] <- "Very Active"

# Print a table of the TotalSteps_category variable
table(merge_all2$TotalSteps_category)
```

Output:

```
FALSE Less Active 
    1         942
```

I'm expecting the output to show the results for less, moderate, active, and very active, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to R! Questions tend to be a lot easier to help when we have representative sample data. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(merge_all2,20))` (perhaps more than 20 if we _need_ it for reproduction of your issue).

Comment: Your first line created a `logical` (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE`) variable in `merge_all2$TotalSteps_category`. It seems to be `TRUE` in all but one case. `merge_all2$TotalSteps_category[merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == 1] <- "Less Active"` assigns `"Less Active"` to all the cases where `merge_all2$TotalSteps_category == TRUE`. (`TRUE == 1` is `TRUE` in R.)